# Analysing time complexity of continuous binary search in infinite array

Tags: time-complexity

I have a sorted array A contains n element, and a sorted array B contains m elements, to find all the matches, and I have an algorithm, I use the binary search in infinite array for each element in B, check each the `2^k-th` element, if find one element is less that the target, use binary search between `2^k` and `2^(k+1]` and use the result as the new start point, check the next element in B. In this way, we can find all the matches between the two arrays.

(I know usually we can merge or iteragte through them to get the result, deciding using this algo is because I cannot compare each element in B array with A's element more than ceil(logn) times)

I wish to this algo can run in O(n) time, how can I prove it? But I am not sure if this algo is really in O(n) time.

One binary search is in O(logn), and n times binary search is O(nlogn), but I feel this algo is much better than O(nlogn).

For example, `A = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11] and B = [3,9]`, index starts from 1.

step1: for the B[1], check A[1], A[2], A[4], in this step, we find that B[1] is in A[2] and A[4], so we use binary search in A[2..4],

step2: for the B[2], we only need to check the elements after the result of previous step. therefore, check A[3] (3 + 2^0), A[4] (3 + 2^1), A[7] (3 + 2^2), A[11] (3 + 2^3), we find that B[2] is in the A[7] and A[11], so we use binary search in A[7..11]

and so on.

```
def continuousBinary(A, n, B, m):
    i = 1
    prevResultIndex = 0
    while i < m:
        k = 0
        while A[prevResultIndex + pow(2,k)] < B[i]:
            k+=1
        prevResultIndex = binarySearch(B[i], A, prevResultIndex + pow(2,k-1), prevResultIndex + pow(2,k))
```

This is the code I implemented for this question.

Comment: *" find m sorted elements in A"*: what does that mean? Can you give example inputs and corresponding outputs?

Comment: @trincot I have added an example to the body of question, thank you for remind me of this.

Comment: *"index starts from 1. step1: for the B[0]..."*: what is B[0] if index starts from 1?

Comment: @trincot, oh yes, means the first element, sorry for the mistake, I changed that

Comment: You have added an example to explain your algorithm, but what I am looking for is an explanation of what the expected output is for a given input. This may be obvious to you, but after rereading I still don't get what the exercise is.

Comment: @trincot, this algo is to find all the matches between two sorted array, while each element cannot compare with others more than ceil(logn) times, I have added this part.

Comment: Why don't you implement the algorithm and see how it performs? My guess is `O(log n)`

Comment: @Jocke, I just updated the question with an implementation, in the code, there are m times while loop and each one do a binary search, can you give me any clue of how I should analyse the time complexity

Comment: There is no such thing as 'binary search in infinite array'. You can't chop something infinite in half. Please clarify your question.

Comment: @user207421 They're not saying they use binary search on the whole array. They say *"binary search between 2^k and 2^(k+1]"*. Standard part of standard  exponential search. (But I find it unclear why they're doing that and why they're talking about infinite, since the array actually has size n and they know n, so they could just do an ordinary binary search.)

Comment: Why do you say *"n times binary search"* when you clearly do m?

Comment: @KellyBundy, the two array should have the same length in the worst case, but I want to make it clearthat which index represents A or B array in the code. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: Not sure how you mean worst case. If you have two independent sizes, you can't ignore one. Since m can be arbitrarily larger than n, neither O(n) nor O(n log n) are right. (But I think your algorithm is O(m+n), though my reasoning is vague so far.)

Comment: What's the logarithm base in "ceil(logn)"?

Comment: @KellyBundy, it is the ceiling operation, to ensure that the result is enough for binary search over n length array.

Comment: @KellyBundy, m is smaller than n, so I think the worst situation is I have the largest m, which is n, and your are right, I should think more in the definition of the worst case, now I think the worst case is to equally seprate the array, so that the time complexity in the second layer is 2*log(n/2), which is higher than any other proportion of seperation (e.g. 2*log(n/2) > log(n/3) + log(2n/3)).

Comment: I know what ceil is. I asked about the logarithm base. If it's e or 2, I think you exceed that. I don't see "m is smaller than n" in the question. If that's the case, that should be mentioned.